# UITextFieldShouldReturn does not work with my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I have searched the entire internet and tried different ways to implement `UITextFieldShouldReturn`, but when I run it in the simulator it just doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is move from the first textfield(`emailTextField`) to the second one( `nameTextField` ) when user clicks next button on the keyboard. The same for the second textfield's keyboard and dismiss the keyboard when user clicks done button on the last textfield( `numberTextField` ).

Here is my code, can anyone help me with this?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.emailTextField.placeholder = @"Your Pitt Email(optional)";
self.nameTextField.placeholder = @"Lost ID Name";
self.numberTextField.placeholder = @"Lost ID Series Number(optional)";

[self.emailTextField.delegate  self];
[self.nameTextField.delegate self];
[self.numberTextField.delegate  self];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//release delegate
-(void)dealloc{
self.emailTextField.delegate = nil;
self.nameTextField.delegate = nil;
self.numberTextField.delegate = nil;
}

//dismiss keyboard when it's called
-(void)dismissKeyboard{
[self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

//when a textfield begins editing, this will happen
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if(textField == self.emailTextField){
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}else if(textField == self.nameTextField){
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}else{
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}
}

//when a textfield ends editing, this will happen
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if(textField == self.emailTextField){
    textField.placeholder = @"Your Pitt Email(optional)";
    [self textFieldShouldReturn:self.emailTextField];
}else if(textField == self.nameTextField){
    textField.placeholder = @"Lost ID Name";
    [self textFieldShouldReturn:self.nameTextField];
}else{
    textField.placeholder = @"Lost ID Series Number(Optional)";
    [self textFieldShouldReturn:self.numberTextField];
}
}

//return button set up
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

//when confirm is pressed
- (IBAction)confirmButton:(id)sender {
[self dismissKeyboard];
}
@end`
```

[image: This is my UI]

Comment: why you are playing with placeholder? it will automatically go when you start typing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
[self.emailTextField.delegate  self];
```

to

```
self.emailTextField.delegate = self;
```

Also remove those delegates from dealloc. You can put them from `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! Can you tell me what the difference is? Why dot works but square brackets don't?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet. Here i am taking only two 
UITextFields.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField==_txtEmail)
    {
        [_txtEmail resignFirstResponder];
        [_txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField==_txtPassword)
    {
        [_txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the delegate right. Then You need to give your next textfield the `becomeNextResponder` call which should be ideally done in the `shouldReturn` delegate method.
In your `viewDidLoad` method, paste this.

```
self.emailTextField.tag = 2000;
self.nameTextField.tag = 3000;
self.numberTextField.tag = 4000;
```

Now edit your `textFieldShouldReturn` method like this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
if(textfield.tag<4000)
{
   UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1000];
[nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is enough to return keyboard from text fields.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

Your these 3 lines are not working.

```
[self.emailTextField.delegate  self];
[self.nameTextField.delegate self];
[self.numberTextField.delegate  self];
```

If you are using storyboard, connect delegates of the text fields with the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.It is working for me..

```
-(void)tool{

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[toolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];
[doneButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *Next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Nextbutton)];
[Next setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Next,flexButton,doneButton,nil];
[toolbar setItems:itemsArray];


[FirstNameTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
[LastNameTextfield setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
[EmailAddressTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
[PasswordTextfield setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
[ConfirmPasswordTextfield setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];}

-(void)Nextbutton{
if ([FirstNameTextField isFirstResponder])
{
    [LastNameTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ([LastNameTextfield isFirstResponder])
{
    [EmailAddressTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ([EmailAddressTextField isFirstResponder])
{
    [PasswordTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ([PasswordTextfield isFirstResponder])
{
    [ConfirmPasswordTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ([ConfirmPasswordTextfield isFirstResponder])
{
    [ConfirmPasswordTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}}

-(void)resignKeyboard{
[FirstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[EmailAddressTextField resignFirstResponder];
[LastNameTextfield resignFirstResponder];
[PasswordTextfield resignFirstResponder];
[ConfirmPasswordTextfield resignFirstResponder];}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can always use a library to accomplish what you need to do !! 
use this library : [tpAvoidKeyboard](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Read how to use it and there you go all the next buttons and clicks outside text fields to dismiss the keyboard and the the done button on the last textfield to dismiss the keyboard, all those features are already implemented

Comment: what you want to accomplish is the next buttons on the keyboard from one text field to another and you want to be able to dismiss the keyboard on the last text field right ? then this library should work for you i used it before and it is awsome @FahimParkar